# How to get particular infomation stored in list

Tags: c#, winforms, collections

I am using a existing web service which does a postcode search its then stored In a list box the values: *"ID", "Text", "Highlight", "Cursor", "Description", "Next".* I need to try and access a particular string value which is the *ID & Next* param and use it for validation later on. When I click on the list box I want the particular data to be taken stored then access the two pieces of information I need.  How do I access the information on a particular row of the list box and use that later on?

```
try
{
    int myMaxResultValue = (int)nud_MaxResults.Value;
    int myMaxSuggestValue = (int)nud_MaxSuggestions.Value;
    findResults = objBvSoapClient.CapturePlus_Interactive_Find_v2_10("Dak4-KZ62-AAdd87-X55", txt_Search.Text, txt_LastId.Text, cb_SearchFor.Text, text_Country.Text, text_LanguagePreference.Text, myMaxResultValue, myMaxSuggestValue);

    if (txt_Search.Text.Length <= 2)// if less than two letters are entered nothing is displayed on the list.
    {
        ls_Output.Items.Clear();// Clear LstBox
        ls_Output.Items.Add(String.Format(allDetails, "ID", "Text", "Highlight", "Cursor", "Description", "Next"));
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter more than 2 Chars!!");
    }
    else if (txt_Search.Text.Length >= 3)// if greater than or equal to 3 letters in the search box  continue search.
    {
        // Get Results and store in given array.
        foreach (var items in findResults)
        {  //Loop through our collection of found results and change resulting value.
            ls_Output.Items.Add(String.Format(allDetails, items.Id, items.Text.ToString(), items.Highlight, items.Cursor, items.Description, items.Next));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use object of a class PostCodeSearchResult?

Comment: @devil_coder I have allready got the address from mycu rrent service what I need to do is found out how to access the information on a particular row of the list box and use that later on

Comment: Have you tried int index = listBox1.FindString(searchString); ?

Answer (score 1):

As a side note your string.Format missing the variables in the string. It should be more like this

```
int id = 30;
string text = "Hello";
string.Format("This is the ID {0}. Here is some text {1}.", id, text);
```

The output will be "This is the ID 30. Here is some text Hello.".

To answer your question, you'll have to parse it to pull out the parts you want. You could use regex.split to do this. For example, if it's delimited on space you could do something like this

```
string[] data = Regex.Split(operation, @"\s+");
```

Then you can access it like this

```
string required = data[3];
```